# How to deploy database files with Visual Studio Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

- I have to find a suitable location to deploy my SDF (database) file.
- The file must be the same to all users
- Windows applications can't write to the ProgramFiles folder.
- One user can't access other user's AppData folder
- A good choice would be `%ProgramData%`
- In Visual Studio Setup Project File System view, when I right click the output folders I don't have the `%ProgramData%` option

How to write to that folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing to AppData from a Setup & Deployment Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562151/writing-to-appdata-from-a-setup-deployment-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

[Specifying c:\ProgramData folder in Setup project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3729010/114029)

[Winforms Deployment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/ecc74fe3-e11a-4a6a-ae4b-70b8d4ffed8d)

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

CommonApplicationData is `C:\ProgramData` on Windows > Vista, and something like `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users` on XP.

Comment: I suppose that should be `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` for the `%ProgramData%` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this question is a duplicate.  Here is the real way tell VDPROJ to deploy to that location:

[Writing to AppData from a Setup & Deployment Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562151/writing-to-appdata-from-a-setup-deployment-project)

But that will leave another problem:  Standard Users won't have write privs to that directory.  You'll either have to write a custom action to open it up or you'll have to use a better MSI authoring tool such as Windows Installer XML (open source) or InstallShield 2010LE ( free ) that has proper support for defining resource permissions.

Comment: normal users also don't have permission to install new programs. So I don't think it would be a problem, since probably the installer will be running with admin permissions.

Comment: What I am saying is an Admin will install your application but when a standard user ( or an admin with UAC enabled ) runs code that tries to write to your database  it will throw an exception.