# How to include arbitrary files in a .NET setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje, visual-studio-setup

We have a folder of text files that needs to be copied to the server whenever our application is deployed. Currently, we handle this by manually copying/pasting the folder's contents.

How can I include this as an automated step in the MSI?

I want the folder (and it's contents) to be included in the MSI. Then, on install, I want to the files in the MSI to overwrite the existing files (in a given local directory).

The files are in source control (TFS), but they are not part of any .NET project.

I've used the [Nullsoft Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) before (among others), and that's basically all it does (you tell it what files to pull in and where to put that at install time). Visual Studio automates a lot of this... but I just can't see where to do the basic task.

Comment: Setup projects are deprecated in Visual Studio 2010. They're no longer supported in 2012. You're probably better off using Wix, which is supported under both versions of Visual Studio and most likely in the future version as well.

Comment: Hmmm... Plenty of duplicates over in the "related" links, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562151/writing-to-appdata-from-a-setup-deployment-project
Sounds like Wix is the way to go. Thanks, jesse